# How can I put a condition on the Datatable, "if column 1 has 1, show the next column"?

Tags: c#

I would like Hello, I would like to show in a C# .Net label a question that brings a DataTable from SQL, but with the condition that if the first column of the Datatable has a certain value that the question shows

[image]
I wanted to try this by looping through a DataTable with a Foreach, but I don't know how to perform the condition

Answer (score 0):

you can simply replace the foreach by a for :

```
for(int i=0;i<dt.Columns.Count();i++)
{
    DataColumn dc = dt.Columns[i];
    if(i==0)
    {
        //this will be executed only on first column
    }
}
```

if you ant to keep foreach, you can do like that :

```
bool firstColumn=true;
foreach(DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
{
    if(firstColumn)
    {
        //your code
        firstColumn=false;
    }
}
```

P.S : In future, don't put any screenshot here, copy/paste the code.